# Obtaning maximum likelihood estimator

Tags: statistics

[image]

Hi! The only thing I want to find out is how to obtain the maximum likelihood estimator, nothing about the asymptotic variance. I`ve tried to find it so many times already, that I give up...
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it is $P(X>x)$ rather than $P(x>X)$? Because it does not look like a probability distribution right now: $P(X>x)$ grows when $x$ grows.

Comment: Unfortunately this is what our teacher has sent us. I suppose there is no mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, the formula is inconsistent, i.e.:

$P(X>0) = 0 < P(X>\infty)=1= NONSENSE$...if its guaranteed to be $\infty$ then is must also be guaranteed to be greater than zero. Your teacher may have overlooked this, so I would point this out. Its not a probability distribution as written.

Now..lets assume your teacher actually meant:

$P(X\leq x) = 1- (1+x)^{-\theta}$ this is a valid probability disribution, so we can start the process of deriving the MLE, which is what you wanted to know how to get. Since this is homework, I will not DO the steps, but will outline what you need to do:

1. You need to derive the density function by taking the derivative wrt x of $P(X\leq x)$, lets call this $f(x;\theta)$ to emphasize that it has one parameter, $\theta$ (I assume you know calculus and can take the actual derivative of your probability distribution).
2. As ususal, we will assume the sample is random, so each value is iid. Do you know what the likelihood function is? Its the same thing as the density function, but you treat the observed value as given and treat the parameter(s) as the variables. In this case, you will be multipliying n copies of your density function together, one per sample point, to get your sample likelihood function: $L(\theta;\mathbf{x})=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i;\theta)$.
3. Now, at this point, you could take the deriviative of $L(\theta;\mathbf{x})$ wrt $\theta$ and set it equal to zero, but the derivative of such a large product is tedious. Typically, you take the natual log of the likelihood to get the log-likelihood, which is much easier to work with analytically:

$\mathcal{L}(\theta;\mathbf{x})=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\ln(f(x_i;\theta))$

Finally, take the derivative of the log-likelihood wrt $\theta$ set it to zero and solve for $\theta$ in terms of the $x_i$'s. This will be your maximum likelihood estimator for $\theta$. For completeness, you may want to take the second derivative wrt $\theta$ to verify it is negative and that it doesnt change sign, but normally you have a unimodal loglikelihood with negative curvature, so you should be OK.

Hopefully this answers your question about how to get MLEs. You are just treating the product of single sample points likelihoods and maximizing it wrt your parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it`s more than just complete!